# VLC HTTP STREAMING OVER HTTP IS STOPPING AFTER 10 SECONDS ALWAYS

Tags: http, ffmpeg, video-streaming, vlc, libvlc

I am trying to run my `Ubuntu machine` as `vlc server`. where i run below command to stream my local video over `http.vlc` `1.avi`

`:sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,acodec=vorb,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:duplicate{dst=http{dst=:8080/test.ogg}}       :sout-all :sout-keep`

Below is `vlc client commad` to `display` the `http streaming output` which is stopping always after 10 sec. For subsequent attempt this is not working.`("failed to find url")`
vlc http://localhost:8080/test.ogg .

Please suggest any workaround. Also please let me knwo if i should switched to `ffmpeg` if this is legacy problem. please suggest the command as well.

Note : using the latest vlc

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It plays successfully for 10s? Maybe check your vlc logs.  Maybe what's happening is your client is "giving up" on the stream, and so the server shuts down, probably...

Answer (score 0):

this was vlc version mismatch,once i make same vlc version in both client and server then it works perfectly